# Populating custom fields on checkout page

Tags: php, jquery, woocommerce

I have created two plugins:

1. To add 3 custom fields on register form
2. To add this 3 custom fields on checkout page and user dashboard panel.

I have successfuly added my fields in register form, checkout page and user dashboar panel but on checkout page I cannot populate them with the presaved values.

First plugin is for adding new fields in registration. The new fields are: 'billing_bulstat' ; 'billing_mol' and 'billing_adres'. They are succesfuly saved and displayed in user dashboard panel. The code is:

---

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: WooCommerce Registration Fields in Luga.bg - Traders Store
 * Plugin URI: http://www.luga.bg/traders
 * Description: My Custom registration fields in Luga.bg - Traders Store
 * Version: 2.0
 * Author: Nikolay Grudev
 * Author URI: http://www.luga.bg/traders
 * License: GPL3
 */

/**
 * Add new register fields for WooCommerce registration in Luga.bg - Traders Store.
 *
 * @return string Register fields HTML.
 */
function wooc_extra_register_fields() {
    ?>

    <p class="form-row form-row-first">
    <label for="reg_billing_first_name"><?php _e( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span 

class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_first_name" id="reg_billing_first_name" value="<?php if ( ! 

empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ); ?>" />
    </p>

    <p class="form-row form-row-last">
    <label for="reg_billing_last_name"><?php _e( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span 

class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_last_name" id="reg_billing_last_name" value="<?php if ( ! 

empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ); ?>" />
    </p>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
    <label for="reg_billing_company"><?php _e( 'Име на фирмата', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span 

class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_company" id="reg_billing_company" value="<?php if ( ! empty( 

$_POST['billing_company'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_company'] ); ?>" />
    </p>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <p class="form-row form-row-first">
    <label for="reg_billing_bulstat"><?php _e( 'ЕИК', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_bulstat" id="reg_billing_bulstat" value="<?php if ( ! empty( 

$_POST['billing_bulstat'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_bulstat'] ); ?>" />
    </p>

    <p class="form-row form-row-last">
    <label for="reg_billing_city"><?php _e( 'City', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_city" id="reg_billing_city" value="<?php if ( ! empty( 

$_POST['billing_city'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_city'] ); ?>" />
    </p>

    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
    <label for="reg_billing_mol"><?php _e( 'МОЛ (Материално отговорно лице)', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span 

class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_mol" id="reg_billing_mol" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST

['billing_mol'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_mol'] ); ?>" />
    </p>

    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
    <label for="reg_billing_adres"><?php _e( 'Адрес за фактуриране', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span 

class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_adres" id="reg_billing_adres" value="<?php if ( ! empty( 

$_POST['billing_adres'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_adres'] ); ?>" />
    </p>

    <?php
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start', 'wooc_extra_register_fields' );

/**
 * Validate the extra register fields.
 *
 * @param  string $username          Current username.
 * @param  string $email             Current email.
 * @param  object $validation_errors WP_Error object.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function wooc_validate_extra_register_fields( $username, $email, $validation_errors ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'billing_first_name_error', __( '<strong>Грешка</strong>: Първото име е 

задъжлително!', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'billing_last_name_error', __( '<strong>Грешка</strong>: Фамилията е 

задължителна!.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_company'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_company'] ) ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'billing_company_error', __( '<strong>Грешка</strong>: Името на фирмата е 

задължително!.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_bulstat'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_bulstat'] ) ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'billing_bulstat_error', __( '<strong>Грешка</strong>: ЕИК на фирмата е 

задължителен!.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_city'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_city'] ) ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'billing_city_error', __( '<strong>Грешка</strong>: Градът е задължителен!.', 

'woocommerce' ) );
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_mol'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_mol'] ) ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'billing_mol_error', __( '<strong>Грешка</strong>: МОЛ е задължително!.', 

'woocommerce' ) );
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_adres'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_adres'] ) ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'billing_adres_error', __( '<strong>Грешка</strong>: Адресът за фактуриране е 

задължителен!.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_register_post', 'wooc_validate_extra_register_fields', 10, 3 );

/**
 * Save the extra register fields.
 *
 * @param  int  $customer_id Current customer ID.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function wooc_save_extra_register_fields( $customer_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) {
        // WordPress default first name field.
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'first_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) );

        // WooCommerce billing first name.
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_first_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) );
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) {
        // WordPress default last name field.
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'last_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) );

        // WooCommerce billing last name.
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_last_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) );
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_company'] ) ) {
        // WooCommerce company name
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'company', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_company'] ) );

        // WooCommerce billing company name.
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_company', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_company'] ) );
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_bulstat'] ) ) {
        // WooCommerce company bulstat
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'bulstat', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_bulstat'] ) );

       // WooCommerce billing company bulstat
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_bulstat', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_bulstat'] ) );
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_city'] ) ) {
        // WooCommerce company city
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'city', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_city'] ) );

        // WooCommerce billing company city
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_city', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_city'] ) );
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_mol'] ) ) {
        // WooCommerce company mol
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'mol', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_mol'] ) );

        // WooCommerce billing company mol
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_mol', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_mol'] ) );
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_adres'] ) ) {
        // WooCommerce company address
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'adres', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_adres'] ) );

        // WooCommerce billing company address
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_adres', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_adres'] ) );
    }

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'wooc_save_extra_register_fields' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'ws_billing_fields_save', 10, 1 );

function ws_billing_fields_save( $user_id ){
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_bulstat'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_bulstat', $_POST['billing_bulstat']);
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_mol'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_mol', $_POST['billing_mol']);
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_adres'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_adres', $_POST['billing_adres']);
    }
}





/**
 * Dopylnitelni poleta v User Profil na Dashboard v Wordpress
 */

function eri_add_custom_user_profile_fields( $user ) {
?>

    <!-- Field Title -->
    <h3><?php _e('Company Information', 'eribootstrap'); ?></h3>

    <table class="form-table">

        <tr>
            <th>
                <label for="billing_bulstat">
                <?php _e('ЕИК', 'eribootstrap'); ?>
            </label>
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="billing_bulstat" id="billing_bulstat" value="<?php echo 

esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'billing_bulstat', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
                <span class="description"><?php _e('Въведи ЕИК.', 'eribootstrap'); ?></span>
            </td>
        </tr><!-- field ends here -->
                <tr>
            <th>
                <label for="billing_mol"><?php _e('МОЛ', 'eribootstrap'); ?>
            </label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="billing_mol" id="billing_mol" value="<?php echo esc_attr( 

get_the_author_meta( 'billing_mol', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
                <span class="description"><?php _e('Въведете МОЛ на фирмата', 'eribootstrap'); ?

></span>
            </td>
        </tr><!-- field ends here -->
<tr>
<th>
<label for="billing_adres"><?php _e('Адрес за фактуриране', 'eribootstrap'); ?>
</label></th>
<td>
<textarea name="billing_adres" id="billing_adres"  class="regular-text"><?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 

'billing_adres', $user->ID ) ); ?>
</textarea><br />
<span class="description"><?php _e('Въведете адрес за фактуриране', 'eribootstrap'); ?></span>
</td>
</tr><!-- field ends here -->
    </table>
<?php }

function eri_save_custom_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
        return FALSE;

    // Update and Save Field
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'billing_bulstat', $_POST['billing_bulstat'] );
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'billing_mol', $_POST['billing_mol'] );
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'billing_adres', $_POST['billing_adres'] );
}

add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'eri_add_custom_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'eri_add_custom_user_profile_fields' );

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'eri_save_custom_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'eri_save_custom_user_profile_fields' );
```

---

The second plugin adds three new custom field on checkout page. They are displayed, but are not automaticaly populated. I use  $checkout->get_value( 'my_field_name' ) ); function, but is doesn't work.

I want they to be automatic populated with the presaved values. The fields are the same: 'billing_bulstat' ; 'billing_mol' and 'billing_adres'. The code is:

---

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Woocommerce Checkout fileds
Plugin URI: https://www.luga.bg/traders
Description: Customized Woocommerce checkout fields
Version: 1
Author: Nikolay Grudev
Author URI: http://www.luga.bg/
*/
/**
* set customized Woocommerce checkout fields
*/

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'customize_fields' );

function customize_fields( $fields ) {

    // make fields required:
    $fields['billing']['billing_company']['required']   = true;

    return $fields;
}

// Remove some checkout billing fields
function kia_filter_billing_fields($fields){
    unset( $fields["billing_country"] );
    unset( $fields["billing_address_1"] );
    unset( $fields["billing_address_2"] );
    unset( $fields["billing_state"] );
    unset( $fields["billing_postcode"] );
    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'kia_filter_billing_fields' );

/**
 * Add the field to the checkout
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field' );

function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

    echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field"><h2>' . __('Extra Information') . '</h2>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 
    'billing_bulstat', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('EIK'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Enter something'),
        'required'     => true,
        ),$checkout->get_value( 'billing_bulstat' ) );

    woocommerce_form_field( 
    'billing_mol', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('MOL'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Enter something'),
        'required'     => true,
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'billing_mol' ) );

    woocommerce_form_field( 
    'billing_adres', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('Adres za fakturirane'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Enter something'),
        'required'     => true,
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'billing_adres' ) );

    echo '</div>';

}
/**
 * Validate the custom field.
 */
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if ( ! $_POST['billing_bulstat'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter something into this new shiny field.' ), 'error' );
    if ( ! $_POST['billing_mol'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter something into this new shiny field.' ), 'error' );
    if ( ! $_POST['billing_adres'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter something into this new shiny field.' ), 'error' );
}
/**
 * Save the order meta with field value
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );

function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_bulstat'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'billing_bulstat', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_bulstat'] ) );
    }
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_mol'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'billing_mol', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_mol'] ) );
    }
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_adres'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'billing_adres', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_adres'] ) );
    }
}
/**
 * Display field value on the order edit page
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 

'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );

function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Extra Information').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'billing_bulstat', true ) 

. '</p>';
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Extra Information').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'billing_mol', true ) . 

'</p>';
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Extra Information').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'billing_adres', true ) . 

'</p>';
}

// display the extra data on order recieved page and my-account order review
function kia_display_order_data( $order_id ){  ?>
    <h2><?php _e( 'Additional Info' ); ?></h2>
    <table class="shop_table shop_table_responsive additional_info">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th><?php _e( 'Bulstat: ' ); ?></th>
                <td><?php echo get_post_meta( $order_id, 'billing_bulstat', true ); ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><?php _e( 'MOL: ' ); ?></th>
                <td><?php echo get_post_meta( $order_id, 'billing_mol', true ); ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><?php _e( 'Adres za fakturirane: ' ); ?></th>
                <td><?php echo get_post_meta( $order_id, 'billing_adres', true ); ?></td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
    </table>
<?php }
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'kia_display_order_data', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_view_order', 'kia_display_order_data', 20 );


// display the extra data in the order admin panel
function kia_display_order_data_in_admin( $order ){  ?>
    <div class="order_data_column">
        <h4><?php _e( 'Danni za firmata', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h4>
        <?php 
            echo '<p><strong>' . __( 'Firma: ' ) . '</strong>' . get_post_meta( $order->id, '_billing_company', true 

) . '</p>';
            echo '<p><strong>' . __( 'Bulstat: ' ) . '</strong>' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'billing_bulstat', 

true ) . '</p>';
            echo '<p><strong>' . __( 'MOL: ' ) . '</strong>' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'billing_mol', true ) . 

'</p>';
            echo '<p><strong>' . __( 'Adres za fakturirane: ' ) . '</strong>' . get_post_meta( $order-

>id, 'billing_adres', true ) . '</p>'; ?>
    </div>
<?php }
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details', 'kia_display_order_data_in_admin' );
// WooCommerce 2.3+
function kia_email_order_meta_fields( $fields, $sent_to_admin, $order ) {
    $fields['billing_bulstat'] = array(
                'label' => __( 'Bulstat' ),
                'value' => get_post_meta( $order->id, 'billing_bulstat', true ),
            );
    $fields['billing_mol'] = array(
                'label' => __( 'MOL' ),
                'value' => get_post_meta( $order->id, 'billing_mol', true ),
            );
    $fields['billing_adres'] = array(
                'label' => __( 'Adrez za fakturirane' ),
                'value' => get_post_meta( $order->id, 'billing_adres', true ),
            );
    return $fields;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 'kia_email_order_meta_fields', 10, 3 );


?>
```

---

**Where I am wrong? Why I my fields are not populated atomaticaly with their values?**

Thanks for help!
the site is www.luga.bg/traders

Comment: I am sorry, It is about Woocommerce :)